# Logic for looping

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript function, where the loop should run 10 times, during these 10 times, it should throw a random question based on *,+ and - operations, in that too there should be 4 "+" questions, 3 "-" questions and 3 "*" questions. And the loop should not run more than 10 times, someone please frame a logic for this...

My code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var op=new Array();
        var addCount=0;
        var subCount=0;
        var mulCount=0;
        var counter=0;
        var no;
        op[0]="+";
        op[1]="-";
        op[2]="x";

        Array.prototype.chooseRandom = function() 
        {
            return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
        };
        var a = [1, 2];
        var b = [0, 2];
        var c = [0, 1];

            no=Math.floor((Math.random()*3));
            while(addCount < 4|| subCount < 3 || mulCount < 3)
            {

                    no=Math.floor((Math.random()*3));
                    if(no==0)
                    {
                        if(addCount<4)
                        {
                            addCount++;
            var op1=Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 10+1)) + 10;
                var op2=Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 10+1)) + 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            no=a.chooseRandom();
                        }
                    }       
                    else if(no==1)
                    {
                        if(subCount<3)
                        {
                            subCount++;
            var no1=Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 10+1)) + 10;
            var no2=Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 10+1)) + 10;
                            if(no1>no2)
                            {
                                 var op1=no1;
                                 var op2=no2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var op1=no2;
                                var op2=no1;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            no=b.chooseRandom();
                        }
                    }
                    else if(no==2)
                    {
                        if(mulCount<3)
                        {
                            mulCount++;
            var op1=Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 10+1)) + 10;
            var op2=Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1+1)) + 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            no=c.choseRandom();
                        }
                    }

                    counter++;
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: post your code you've tried so far

Comment: @polin, here's the code, please review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array containing required number of `+`, `-` and `*` then random sort that aray using function below:

```
arr.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})
```

Comment: Why 0.5?? Can u explain the logic in detail?

Comment: Because sort function needs to return negative or positive. Whereas random() returns 0 to 1 that means always positive. Subtract it by 0.5 so returned value ranges from -0.5 to 0.5.

Comment: But I do not require negative values, y u need negative values in whole number operations?

Comment: @Hazel To sort the operations.

Comment: Can u still explain in detail, y we need 0.5 for "sorting"!!??

Comment: Sorting requires comparing two numbers `(a, b)`, is a < b then -1 is returned else + number..then sorter arranges the numbers according to the sign of number returned. I put 0.5 so number returned are equal likely to be either in `-` or in `+`..if I would have just done random() then all number would be positive and nothing would have happened!

Comment: Thnx exactly I am able to generate numbers from 1 to 10 now in a shuffled way without repeating. !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hoping it will help -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function shuffle(o) {
        for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
    }

    function getQuestions(){
        var operators = shuffle(["+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", "x", "x", "x"]);
        var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
        var counter = 0;

        Array.prototype.chooseRandom = function () {
            return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
        };

        while (counter < 10) {
            var op1 = a.chooseRandom();
            var op2 = a.chooseRandom();
            alert(op1 + operators[counter] + op2 + "?")
            counter++;
        }
    }

    getQuestions();
</script>
```

Comment: @Hazel - shuffle is use to shuffle operators array, So that you can get a random array of operators.